Creating three versions of Beamer presentation
I'm teaching a class where my presentations are a mix of explanations and quizzes/questions to the students. I would like to have three versions of my presentations:

All slides, including animations (this I can achieve)
All slides, no animation (this I can achieve using the handout option)
Same as 2. but without the slides with quizzes/questions (this is the one that troubles me)

I am aware of the \includeonlyframes command, but I would like to avoid giving each frame a unique label. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

You could abuse the transparency  mode. Like the handout mode, it also doesn't have animation and you can exclude certain frames  from this mode using <trans:0>:
\documentclass[
%  handout,
  trans,
]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  all
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<trans:0>
  quiz \pause 
  answer
\end{frame}
\end{document}


This does exactly what I need, thanks!

@SuneSørensen You're welcome!

Hmmm... (Humbly asking forgivness to @samcarter). If you can tolerate the "duplicated frame label" warning(*), this works:
\documentclass[
%  handout,
]{beamer}

\includeonlyframes{type1}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=type1]
  type1 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=type1]
  type1 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=type2]
  type2 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=type2]
  type2 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=type1]
  type1 3
\end{frame}
\end{document}

... I mean, you have the warning, but then you can select all the "blocks" you need and it works. If it's just an accident, I do not know...

(*) No, I will not say how to silence the warnings...

+1 for not saying how to silence the warnings :P
